# Why am I getting a java.lang.NullPointerException error in a wifip2p connection

Tags: java, android, wifip2p

Here is the error - java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.wdchat.MainActivity$SendReceive.write(byte[])' on a null object reference.
I have included my mainactivity class code and wifibroadcastreceover class code as well. The code is actually from wifip2p tutorial on youtube made by sarthi technology

```
Here is my MainActivity class.



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    AppCompatEditText editText;
    ImageView wifi_on_off_iv, wifi_descovery_iv, send_btn_iv, save_ic_iv, brd_msg_iv;
    TextView username, sentMessage, connectionStatus, tallytext, tallyno;
    WifiManager wifiManager;
    WifiP2pManager p2pManager;
    WifiP2pManager.Channel mchannel;
    String messageText;
    LinearLayout nestedLinearlayout;

    ListView listView;

    ServerClass serverClass;
    ClientClass clientClass;
    SendReceive sendReceive;

    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
    IntentFilter intentFilter;

    List<WifiP2pDevice> peers = new ArrayList<WifiP2pDevice>();
    String[] devicenameArray;
    WifiP2pDevice[] wifiP2pDeviceArray;


    static final int MESSAGE_READ = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initializeViews();
        exqListener();


    }
    Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message message) {
            switch (message.what){
                case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuff = (byte[]) message.obj;
                String temMsg = new String(readBuff, 0, message.arg1);
                sentMessage.setText(temMsg);
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    private void exqListener() {
        wifi_on_off_iv.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
                wifi_on_off_iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_wifi_on);
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                wifi_on_off_iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_wifi_off);

            } else {
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                wifi_on_off_iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_wifi_on);
            }
        });

        wifi_descovery_iv.setOnClickListener(view -> p2pManager.discoverPeers(mchannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                connectionStatus.setText(R.string.discovery_on);
                wifi_descovery_iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_wifi_discover);
                connectionStatus.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.purple_500));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int i) {
                connectionStatus.setText(R.string.discovery_off);
                wifi_descovery_iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_wifi_discovery_off);
                connectionStatus.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.red));
            }
        }));

        p2pManager.createGroup(mchannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int i) {

            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view, i, l) -> {
            final WifiP2pDevice device = wifiP2pDeviceArray[i];
            WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
            config.deviceAddress = device.deviceAddress;
            p2pManager.connect(mchannel, config, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connected to " + device.deviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int i) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Not connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        });

        send_btn_iv.setOnClickListener(view -> {
           // sendReceive = new SendReceive(sock);
            messageText = Objects.requireNonNull(editText.getText()).toString().trim();
            sendReceive.write(messageText.getBytes());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "you sent"+ messageText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });

    }


    private void initializeViews() {

        intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.mdboard_toolbar);
        wifi_on_off_iv = findViewById(R.id.md_wifi);
        wifi_descovery_iv = findViewById(R.id.md_wifi_descov);
        brd_msg_iv = findViewById(R.id.md_broadcast_mesaage);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.md_editext);
        sentMessage = findViewById(R.id.md_tally_message);
        send_btn_iv = findViewById(R.id.md_send_btn);
        save_ic_iv = findViewById(R.id.md_save);
        username = findViewById(R.id.md_profile_username);
        connectionStatus = findViewById(R.id.md_status_text);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.md_list_view);
        tallytext = findViewById(R.id.md_tally_text);
        tallyno = findViewById(R.id.md_tally_no);
        nestedLinearlayout = findViewById(R.id.nestedscroll_linearlayout);


        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.dashboard);
        ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(nestedLinearlayout, true);

        wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        p2pManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        mchannel = p2pManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);

        broadcastReceiver = new WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver(p2pManager, mchannel, this);

}

    WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener peerListListener = new WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList wifiP2pDeviceList) {
            if (!wifiP2pDeviceList.getDeviceList().equals(peers)) {
                peers.clear();
                peers.addAll(wifiP2pDeviceList.getDeviceList());

                devicenameArray = new String[wifiP2pDeviceList.getDeviceList().size()];
                wifiP2pDeviceArray = new WifiP2pDevice[wifiP2pDeviceList.getDeviceList().size()];
                int index = 0;

                for (WifiP2pDevice device: wifiP2pDeviceList.getDeviceList()) {
                    devicenameArray[index] = device.deviceName;
                    wifiP2pDeviceArray[index] = device;
                    index++;
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, devicenameArray);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            if (peers.size()==0) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No device found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    };
    WifiP2pManager.ConnectionInfoListener connectionInfoListener = new WifiP2pManager.ConnectionInfoListener(){
        @Override
        public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(WifiP2pInfo wifiP2pInfo) {
            final InetAddress groupOwner = wifiP2pInfo.groupOwnerAddress;

            if (wifiP2pInfo.groupFormed && wifiP2pInfo.isGroupOwner){
                connectionStatus.setText("Host");
                serverClass = new ServerClass();
                serverClass.start();
            } else if (wifiP2pInfo.groupFormed){
                connectionStatus.setText("CLient");
                clientClass  = new ClientClass(groupOwner);
                clientClass.start();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        exqListener();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }
    public class ServerClass extends Thread {
        Socket socket;
        ServerSocket serverSocket;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                sendReceive = new SendReceive(socket);
                sendReceive.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private class SendReceive extends Thread{
        private Socket socket;
        private InputStream inputStream;
        private OutputStream outputStream;

        public SendReceive(Socket skt) {
            socket = skt;
            try {
                inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            while (socket!=null) {
                try {
                    bytes = inputStream.read(buffer);
                    if (bytes>0){
                        handler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        public void  write(byte[] bytes){
            outputStream = new OutputStream() {
                @Override
                public void write(int i) throws IOException {
                    outputStream.write(bytes);
                }
            };

        }

    }

    public class ClientClass extends Thread {
        Socket socket;
        String hostAdd;

        public  ClientClass(InetAddress hostAddress) {
            hostAdd = hostAddress.getHostAddress();
            socket = new Socket();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostAdd, 8888),500);
                sendReceive = new SendReceive(socket);
                sendReceive.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // requestGroupInfo
    private void requestGroupInfo() {
        p2pManager.requestGroupInfo(mchannel, new WifiP2pManager.GroupInfoListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupInfoAvailable(WifiP2pGroup wifiP2pGroup) {
                connectionStatus.setText("request group info");
            }
        });
    }
}

Here is my wifibroadcastReceiver class

public class WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    WifiP2pManager wifiP2pManager;
    WifiP2pManager.Channel channel;
    MainActivity mainActivity;

    public WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager mManager, WifiP2pManager.Channel mchannel, MainActivity mActivity) {
        this.wifiP2pManager = mManager;
        this.channel = mchannel;
        this.mainActivity = mActivity;
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){
            int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
            if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
                mainActivity. wifi_on_off_iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_wifi_on);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Wifi is on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else  {
                mainActivity.wifi_on_off_iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_wifi_off);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Wifi is off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else if(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // do somethimg
            if (wifiP2pManager != null) {
                wifiP2pManager.requestPeers(channel, mainActivity.peerListListener);
            }
        } else if(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // do somthing
            if (wifiP2pManager == null) {
                return;
            }
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                wifiP2pManager.requestConnectionInfo(channel, mainActivity.connectionInfoListener);
                mainActivity.connectionStatus.setText("[Device connected]");
                mainActivity.wifi_descovery_iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_wifi_discover);
            } else {
                mainActivity.connectionStatus.setText("[Device disconnected]");
                mainActivity.wifi_descovery_iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_wifi_discovery_off);
            }
        }else if(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
          
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: which line are you getting the NPE at? plus, please only share the relevanet part of the code.

Comment: Looks like messageText.getBytes() is null